# How to configure the paho mqtt subscribe to get the data with high speed like 1000 message per second

Tags: python, mqtt

I am using python **paho mqtt client** to subscribe the MQTT broker to get the data and I am publishing the data through ESP32 using **pubsubclient.h**.

Data frequency is 1000 messages per sec. for testing I published 100000 messages and I used python paho mqtt to subscribe and collect data. I tested several times but I am getting 22000-30000 messages out of 100000 message.

This the code I am using to subscribe the broker:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to broker")
        client.subscribe("pub_test",2) 
    else:
        print("Connection failed")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print (message.payload)
    
def updateMqtt():
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id="Sathish", clean_session=False, userdata=None, transport="tcp")
    #client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect= on_connect
    print("after on connect")#attach function to callback
    client.on_message= on_message
    print("after on message")#attach function to callback    
    client.connect("192.168.3.101", port=1883)
    client.loop_forever()
   # client.loop_start()
    
updateMqtt()
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be loosing the messages between the broker and this code since you are subscribing at QOS2, it's much more likely the loss is between the ESP32 and the broker since the PubSubClient only supports QOS0

Comment: thank you for response.
i tested with Linux mosquito mqtt, in that i am getting complete 100000 messages those are published by the ESP32 without any loss.